# JPA @MapsId vs @JoinColumn(updatable=false, insertable=false)

Tags: java, jpa

It seems to me that there is virtually no difference between the below two ways of mapping.  Here is an example base on `@MapsId` javadoc:

```
// parent entity has simple primary key

@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id long empId;
   ...
}

// dependent entity uses EmbeddedId for composite key

@Embeddable
public class DependentId {
   String name;
   long empid;   // corresponds to primary key type of Employee
}

@Entity
public class Dependent {
   @EmbeddedId DependentId id;
    ...
   @MapsId("empid")  //  maps the empid attribute of embedded id
   @ManyToOne Employee emp;
}
```

What if I change Dependent's mapping to:

```
@Entity
public class Dependent {
   @EmbeddedId DependentId id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn("empid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   Employee emp;
}
```

What is the difference of the above two approach?

Comment: did you tested it already?

Comment: Yes I did but there are some other strange problems.  But base on the description of document, I cannot find any difference of them.  May you give any hints?

Comment: So wat was the better for you? I used to use JoinColumn and for me it worked. But now I saw MapsId so I am also wondering how it will work ;)

Comment: @Rafik991 Same for me :P I used to use JoinColumn but I see MapsId (maybe it is something new from JPA2? or maybe I missed that in the past).   The reason for this question is simply to get to know the difference  :P

Answer (score 7):

So, I tested @MapsId for my usage when in the table I have only one foregin key it was no different. But for tables where I have two foregin keys to one table like ...
`UserTable`, and `EmailTable`-> `@MapsId(owner)UserTable owner`, `@MapsId(receiver) UserTable receiver` i have problems with that. Hibernate throws exceptions. So i have to back to old @JoinColumn way of doing that. That was a one differemce that I met with that adnotations.

Comment: ya, in fact I faced that exception too but I suspect it is simply something else, because from documentation, MapsId should work for (and is aimed for) such situation.  I am more keen to know the difference, by design of feature, between these two.  However, still thanks a lot for your update as it also tell me that I am not the only one having that exception  ;)  LOL

Answer (score 5):

I am using combination of both @MapsId and @JoinColumn together to avoid getting extra field getting created in DB for associating the entities. IF I ignore @JoinColumn, an extra field is getting created in DB.

```
@Entity
public class BookingsModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SlotDateModel slotDateModelObj;

    @JsonProperty
    String slotnumber;

    @MapsId("memberid")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="memberid",referencedColumnName = "memberid")
    @NotNull
    MemberModel memberModel;
.
.
.
}

@Entity
public class MemberModel implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty
    @Id
    String memberid;

    @JsonProperty
    String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    String phoneno;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany
    Set<BookingsModel> bookings;
    .
    .
    .
    }

@Embeddable
public class SlotDateModel implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String memberid;

    String slotdate;
.
.
.
}
```

**Tables generated with @JoinColumn**

[image: Tables generated with @JoinColumn]

**Table generated when @JoinColumn is commented** Can notice that the extra field "member_model_memberid" is getting added.

[image: Table generated when @JoinColumn is commented]